# Input field doesn't let users change value; getting "NaN" when attempting to change value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field for entering a dollar amount with a default value of "$0.00" in the text box. The requirements for this input field are:

1. The value always has to have a decimal value attached. If there is none, default to ".00".
2. There should be a "$" character in the input field.
3. Users cannot enter non-currency values (e.g. A-Z, special characters)
4. Users cannot enter more than 2 decimal places.

With the code I've written so far, it seems that I cannot change the value properly, instead making the input "NaN" when I try to delete a number. While I can enter in a new number after that, I can only enter a single number, and then I am prevented from entering more numbers after that.

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmxvy893/3/)

I tried using this code to try and force the input field to allow new values to be entered, but I still got NaN values:

```
var decimalIndex = val.indexOf('.');
if (decimalIndex != -1) {
  var wholePart = val.substring(0, decimalIndex);
  var decimalPart = val.substring(decimalIndex + 1);
  if (wholePart.length > 0 && decimalPart.length == 0) {
    val = val.substring(0, decimalIndex) + '.' + val.substring(decimalIndex + 1);
  }
}
```

What changes do I need to make to my code in order to ensure I can enter a value properly?

Comment: `parseFloat` returns `NaN` because the argument contains the dollar symbol.

Comment: when you do this `var parts = val.split('.');`  and `console.log(parts[0])` you will see that the value also contains the dollar simbol, for example if the data is `$7.00` `parts[0] = '$7'` and `parts[1] = '00'`